# Why is Visual studio referring to Npgsql, version 4.0.0.0 when the latest version release by the Npgsql team is Version 2.1.0?

Tags: visual-studio, postgresql, npgsql

I have an ASP.NET application that uses PostgreSQL and is using Npgsql as the Data Driver. Every now and then I keep getting this error :

> > > Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

While in my project references the Npgsql version is 2.1.0

What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: Check your Web.config & assembly references.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of verions mentioned in the properties of a Reference in Visual Studio.

1) Runtime version - Version of the .NET runtime the referenced dll was compiled against

2) Version - version of the referenced dll

Please check your project's targeted .NET version. That should match or should be a later version than that of the referenced dll.